# Discord.NET only admins can run this command

Tags: discord, permissions, discord.net

i want to make a command in Discord.NET that only can be ran by admins.
It would be great if anyone could give me an example thank you!

Comment: [RequirePermission(GuildPermission.Administrator)]

Comment: hey, i tried this multiple times, but it just says nothing is definied, only GuildPermission is, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A command is basically a message that gets sent to the bot. You simply check if the message sender has a specific role ID. An admin role also has a role ID, if the role ID's match, you continue with the command.

Comment: Hey Soufian,
i want to make that its for everyone who uses the bot is, like i know some years ago it was something like this as example [RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.KickMembers)] but this isnt working anymore. You may know how it looks atm? Thanks.